# i build animated container in screen when i go back to another screen i got return animated container and the screen go look bad

Tags: flutter, dart

[photo description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzht9.png)when i go from land scape mode to portatit mode the animated container dadamge the screen
** i build animated container in screen when i go back to another screen i got return animated container and the screen go look bad**

> i build animated container in screen when i go back to another screen i got return animated container and the screen go look bad

```
return Scaffold(
              appBar: appBar,
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>\[
                    if (!isLandScape)
                      Container(
                        height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                                appBar.preferredSize.height -
                                MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
                            0.3,
                        child: Chart(_recentTransactions),
                      ),
        
                    if(isLandScape)
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: \[
                          Text('Show Chart'),
                          Switch(
                              value: showChart,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() {
                                  showChart = val;
                                });
                              })
                        \],
                      ),
                    showChart == true
                        ? AnimatedContainer(
                             duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                             curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
                            height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                                    appBar.preferredSize.height -
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
                                0.7,
                            child: Chart(_recentTransactions))
                        : buildAnimatedContainer(context, appBar),
                  \],
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
              ),
            );
          }


        
          AnimatedContainer buildAnimatedContainer(BuildContext context, AppBar appBar) {
```

> this is buit in method how it work the animated container

```
            return AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              curve: Curves.easeInCubic,
              height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                      appBar.preferredSize.height -
                      MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) *
                  0.7,
              child: TransactionList(_userTransactions, _deleteTransaction),
            );
          }

}[this show how it work when i go to portait mode ][1]
```

> how it works ??

Comment: The image wasnt uploaded properly. unable to understand your requirement

Comment: try now its show

Comment: Look bad, you mean what's happening?